# EXCEL Web scraping from "span" and "a"

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scraper this site where there are no tables (therefore no table, td. Tr etc ..). I should download the data from the tag "a" with class "game" where there are the relative spans inside. Below is what I managed to develop following the post on the notions of scraping. Thanks in advance for your possible help

Run Time error 438 on this line

> For Each HTMLArow In
>   HTMLAtab.getElementsByTagName("a").getElementsByClassName("game")

```
Sub BrowseSiteElementTab()


        Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim HTMLAtab As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim HTMLArow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim HTMLAcel As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

        'costante con in nome della pagina web
        Const myURL As String = "https://sportalic.com/"

        'oggetto IE
        With IE
            .navigate myURL 'naviga a pagina...
            .Visible = True 'visibile ... vero
            Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop 'Attesa not busy
            Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 'Attesa documento
        End With

        'oggetto document
        Set Doc = IE.document

     Set HTMLAtab = Doc.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
        'ciclo per ogni riga della tabella
        For Each HTMLArow In HTMLAtab.getElementsByTagName("a").getElementsByclassName("game")
            'ciclo per ogni cella della riga
            For Each HTMLAcel In HTMLArow.getElementsByTagName("span").getElementsByclassName("tm")
                'stampa nella finestra immediata
                Debug.Print HTMLAcel.innerText
            Next HTMLAcel
        Next HTMLArow

        'Chiusura:
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
        Set Doc = Nothing
        Set HTMLAs = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: You are not asking any questions. The code that you posted works and will successfully print the column "H" from the website in the immediate window. Are you not satisfied with that? What's the problem you're having? Are you getting an error? If so at which line? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It doesn't work, it release me error on `For Each HTMLArow In HTMLAtab.getElementsByTagName("a").getElementsByClassName("game")`
It doesn't print in column "H"

Comment: What does the error say? Please update your question saying what kind of error you're getting and at which line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're treating this: `HTMLAtab.getElementsByTagName("a")` as a single object when in reality it's a collection of all the anchor elements (`<a></a>`) inside `HTMLAtab`.

You don't need this `Set HTMLAtab = Doc.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)` either. You could do this `Set HTMLAtab = Doc.getElementById("games")`, instead.

Basically if you change this `HTMLAtab.getElementsByTagName("a").getElementsByClassName("game")` to this:

`doc.getElementsByClassName("game")` , your code should work.

Having said that, here's how I would do it.

I would avoid using IE. Instead, I would use an HTTP request like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sportalic()

Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim anc As HTMLAnchorElement
Dim sp As HTMLSpanElement
Dim url As String
Dim d As Date

d = Date 'you can change this to whichever date you want
url = "https://sportalic.com/tips/" & Format(d, "yyyy-mm-dd")
With req
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
For Each anc In doc.getElementsByClassName("game")
    For Each sp In anc.getElementsByClassName("tm")
        Debug.Print sp.innerText
    Next sp
Next anc

End Sub
```

This will print column H from the website in the immediate window. You can modify it accordingly to best fit your needs.

For the code above to work you will need to add references to:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1
```

**EDIT**

The website is quite poorly designed imho so I understand your confusion. Here's a complete approach on how to scrape it.

Keep in mind that this `.getElementsByClassName("o")` returns a collection of all the html elements whose class name is `"o"`. To get the `i-th` element from this collection you have to do this `.getElementsByClassName("o")(i-1)` (indexing starts from zero).

```
Option Explicit

Sub sportalic()

Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim anc As HTMLAnchorElement
Dim sp As HTMLSpanElement
Dim url As String, results() As String
Dim d As Date
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio2")
Set rng = sht.Range("A2")
d = Date - 1 'you can change this to whichever date you want
url = "https://sportalic.com/tips/" & Format(d, "yyyy-mm-dd")
With req
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
ReDim results(1 To doc.getElementsByClassName("game").Length, 1 To 13)
i = 0
For Each anc In doc.getElementsByClassName("game")
    i = i + 1
    results(i, 1) = anc.getElementsByClassName("cn")(0).innerText
    results(i, 2) = anc.getElementsByClassName("nm")(0).innerText
    results(i, 3) = anc.getElementsByClassName("nm")(1).innerText
    results(i, 4) = anc.getElementsByClassName("t")(0).innerText
    results(i, 5) = anc.getElementsByClassName("t")(1).innerText
    results(i, 6) = anc.getElementsByClassName("t")(2).innerText
    results(i, 7) = anc.getElementsByClassName("o")(0).innerText
    results(i, 8) = anc.getElementsByClassName("o")(1).innerText
    results(i, 9) = anc.getElementsByClassName("o")(2).innerText
    results(i, 10) = anc.getElementsByClassName("tip")(0).innerText
    results(i, 11) = anc.getElementsByClassName("odd")(0).innerText
''''''check if the game has been completed (the final score is available)''''
    If Not anc.getElementsByClassName("r")(0) Is Nothing Then               '
        results(i, 12) = anc.getElementsByClassName("r")(0).innerText       '
    Else                                                                    '
        results(i, 12) = ""                                                 '
    End If                                                                  '
    If Not anc.getElementsByClassName("r")(1) Is Nothing Then               '
        results(i, 13) = anc.getElementsByClassName("r")(1).innerText       '
    Else                                                                    '
        results(i, 13) = ""                                                 '
    End If                                                                  '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Next anc
rng.Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results 'write the results array into a worksheet in one go

''''''''''''''Prevent numbers from being stored as text''''''''''''''''''''''
With sht                                                                    '
    Set rng = Range(rng, .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 13)) '
End With                                                                    '
rng.Value = rng.Value                                                       '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End Sub
```

Here's how yesterday's results look like:

[image]

Comment: It seems like work, but how i can scrape all table and print in Sheet("Foglio2")?

Comment: Sorry if i distrub you. But i have a problem with some columns. How can divide three equal class and tag? here there are selector

`#g_599593 > span.data > span.tos > span.os > span:nth-child(1)`

`#g_599593 > span.data > span.tos > span.os > span:nth-child(2)`

`#g_599593 > span.data > span.tos > span.os > span:nth-child(3)`


I tried with Trim but it doesn't work

Comment: @FilippoSchiera I can see that you have actually put some effort into this so I decided to help you a bit more. I have updated my answer to do a complete scrape of the table. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. This helps good quality content to remain relevant.